# error el enviar un array de datos por email con laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy enviando un correo a travez de laravel y al pasarlo al controlador mail me da el error

> Array to string conversion

este es el codigo en el controlador

```
public function store(){
        $message = request()->validate([
            'name'      => 'required',
            'email'     => 'required|email',
            'subject'   => 'required',
            'content'   => 'required|min:3',
        ], [
            'name.required' => __('I need your name'),
        ]);

        Mail::to('prueba@test.com')->send(new MessageReceived($message));
        //return new MessageReceived($message);

        return 'Mensaje Enviado';
    }
```

tambien tengo un controlador mail que contiene el siguiente codigo

```
class MessageReceived extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    public $subject = 'Mensaje Recibido';
    public $msg;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($msg)
    {
        $this->$msg = $msg;
        var_dump($msg);
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('emails.message-received');
    }
```

el error me da al enviar el formulario, estoy siguiendo un curso el cual la versionde laravel utilizada es la 5.6 y yo realizo la practica con laravel 7.3

no trabajo con una direccion de correo valida por que estoy tratando de verificar los datos enviados a traves de los log de laravel, si comento la linea:

> $this->$msg = $msg;

los datos se reflejan correctamente en el log pero al habilitarla me da el error antes mecionado.

Answer (score 0):

El error tiene bastante sentido en realidad. No estás pasando a tu clase Mail un valor que sea string para mostrar en el componente que se le enviará al usuario vía Mail, solo pasas un array completo. Estás pasando tu array completo del request que te llega a tu controlador. Por lo tanto tu código debería ser algo así:

```
public function store(){
        $message = request()->validate([
            'name'      => 'required',
            'email'     => 'required|email',
            'subject'   => 'required',
            'content'   => 'required|min:3',
        ], [
            'name.required' => __('I need your name'),
        ]);

        Mail::to('prueba@test.com')->send(new MessageReceived($message));
        //return new MessageReceived($message);

        return 'Mensaje Enviado';
    }
```

class MessageReceived extends Mailable
{
use Queueable, SerializesModels;
public $subject = 'Mensaje Recibido';
public $msg;

```
/**
 * Create a new message instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct($msg)
{
    //Supongo que content es donde almacenas el string de tu formulario via request
    //Entonces solo debes acceder a la key de tu array
    $this->$msg = $msg['content'];
}

/**
 * Build the message.
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function build()
{
    return $this->view('emails.message-received');
}
```

Comment: Me sigue arrojando el mismo error.

Comment: ¿Qué te retorna la variable $message de tu controlador?

Comment: listo el error era que en la linea $this->$msg = $msg; tenia un signo de "$" el cual no iba, al eliminarlo funciono correctamente,